# How can I get JS to "see" html that has been posted to the current page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few JS scripts made to sort and print tables on my website showing my sql tables. I have a reports page that prints a certain table depending on what option you choose in the form, and it shows up on the same page because I used `<form method="post" action="">`

For instance trying to sort my table results in an error in the console that reads:

> TypeError: rows is undefined

Its interesting to me that this is the second line in the script that calls for the table element as you can see

```
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, numdir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("table");
  switching = true;
  // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // Start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /* Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers): */
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      // Start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next: */
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /* Check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc: */
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()){
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()){
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done: */
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      // Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
function sortNum(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, numdir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("table");
  switching = true;
  // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // Start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /* Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers): */
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      // Start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next: */
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /* Check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc: */
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (Number(x.innerHTML) > Number(y.innerHTML)) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (Number(x.innerHTML) < Number(y.innerHTML)) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done: */
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      // Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would work on any of my tables had the not been posted to the same page. Is this possibly a problem with when the JS is loaded in the html document?

Comment: Try running your function in the body.onload event when you want it to run after the table loaded. Or is the table loaded asynchronously by ajax?

Comment: These arent scripts that need to be ran on the tables, theyre buttons. Like click the table header for alphabetical/numerical order, click a button to print. I don't have anything fancy going on with the table loading, the form just uses post and I'm using php for sql, so it looks at the $_POST variables and is just a php if then statement to display the right table